# ¿Cómo puedo entrar al mercado de Steam con mi cuenta usando BeautifulSoup?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

Hace un par de meses desarrolle un código usando BeautifulSoup que me permitía entrar al mercado de Steam con mi cuenta, a través del uso de cookies. El problema es que hoy mi código ya no reconoce la cookie necesaria para entrar a la página con mi cuenta de Steam (Esto lo sé porque los precios de la tienda aparecen en dólares estadounidenses en ves de pesos argentinos) y no logro encontrar la forma de solucionarlo. Aquí mi código:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests


url = "https://steamcommunity.com/market/"

Precios = []

head = {"cookie" : "steamLoginSecure=123456..."}


page = requests.get(url, cookies=head) #Descarga contenido de la página
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, "html.parser") #Transforma a BeautifulSoup
Buscador = soup.find_all("span", attrs = {'data-currency' : "1"}) # Busca lo indicado

for i in Buscador:
    Precios.append(i.text)

print(Precios)
```